# MySQL 1064 error on create table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
> CREATE TABLE If NOT EXISTS HARDWARE
(
'RECORD_ID' int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
'Asset_Number' int(10) unique not null index,
'Type' char(20) not null,
'Name' varchar(50) not null index,
'Device Description' varchar(50) not null,
'Building' char(40) not null index,
'Date Created' date DEFAULT CURDATE() not null,
'Serial Number' varchar(50) index not null,
'Owner' char(50) index,
'User Created' CHAR ON CREATE USER() INDEX,
'Date Modified' date ON UPDATE CURDATE(),
'Purchase Year' int(4),
'Model' char(50),
'User Modified' CHAR(50),
'PO Number' int(20),
'Location' VARCHAR(50) index,
'OS' VARCHAR(20),
'RAM' int(4),
'Notes' text,
'Verified_By_t' char(50) on update user(),
'Internal IP Address' ON UPDATE USER(),
'Verified_Date_d' date ON UPDATE CURDATE(),
'Ethernet MAC' VARCHAR(20) index,
'Wireless MAC' VARCHAR(20) index,
'Usage' VARCHAR(20),
'Funding Source' VARCHAR(20),
'Lock Combo' int(10),
'ServiceLog::Date Created' VARCHAR(20),
'ServiceLog::Issue' VARCHAR(20),
'Ext. Ethernet Adapter' VARCHAR(20),
'AD' bit,
'Updated' date on update CURDATE(),
'Asset LI Hardware::ID Link' VARCHAR(20),
'Hardware' VARCHAR(20),
'Hardware Asset LI::Description' VARCHAR(20),
'Hardware Asset LI::Location' VARCHAR(20),
'Hardware Asset LI::Type' VARCHAR(20),
'Main Menu::Company' VARCHAR(20)
)
```

and the error I am getting is

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''RECORD_ID' int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 'Asset_Number' int unique not null index, ' at line 3

I have tried varying this with:

```
CREATE TABLE If NOT EXISTS HARDWARE
```

(
RECORD_ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Asset_Number int unique not null index,

```
CREATE TABLE If NOT EXISTS HARDWARE
```

(
Asset_Number int unique not null index,

and other variations.
This is what I currently have and instead of one error it shows 5 errors.

```
    CREATE TABLE If NOT EXISTS HARDWARE
(
RECORD_ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Asset_Number int unique not null index,
Type char(20) not null,
Name varchar(50) not null index,
Device_Description varchar(50) not null,
Building char(40) not null index,
Date_Created date DEFAULT CURDATE() not null,
Serial_Number   varchar(50) index not null,
Owner char(50) index,
User_Created CHAR ON CREATE USER() INDEX,
Date_Modified date ON UPDATE CURDATE(),
Purchase_Year int(4),
Model char(50),
User_Modified   CHAR(50),
PO_Number int(20),
Location VARCHAR(50) index,
OS VARCHAR(20),
RAM int(4),
Notes   text,
Verified_By_t   char(50) on update user(),
Internal_IP_Address ON UPDATE USER(),
Verified_Date_d date ON UPDATE CURDATE(),
Ethernet_MAC VARCHAR(20) index,
Wireless_MAC VARCHAR(20) index,
Usage VARCHAR(20),
Funding_Source VARCHAR(20),
Lock_Combo int(10),
AD bit,
Updated_date on update CURDATE()
)
```

and the error I see for it:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index, Type char(20) not null, Name varchar(50) not null index, Device_Descripti' at line 4

Comment: Seems like a fairly straight forward error message.

Comment: I probably just am not understanding the error. When I have the quotes around the column names it only shows one error but when I remove the quotes it shows 5 errors. The first error is showing on `'RECORD_ID' int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,` which is the line 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have numerous errors in your code.  Here are some that I've spotted:

- The `index` should be a separate line, not inline.
- MySQL supports `ON UPDATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` . . . for one column and that column should be a `datetime`.
- There is no `ON UPDATE USER()`.
- The IP Address does not have a type.
- There is no `ON CREATE`.

(Note: Perhaps the most recent version of MySQL *does* support some of these options, but they don't look familiar to me.)

I would suggest that you create the table starting with the first column -- say by commenting out all the other columns.  Then, add one column at a time and fix the errors as you encounter them.

Comment: He's also using type and that's a [keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try.